# Can you help me with this? typing-extensions 4.6.0 - 4.8.0

Tags: google-colaboratory

I get this kind of error on Google Colab and everything is normal on my computer, how can I solve this situation?

ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts. lida 0.0.10 requires kaleido, which is not installed. tensorflow 2.13.0 requires typing-extensions<4.6.0,>=3.6.6, but you have typing-extensions 4.8.0 which is incompatible.

I did all the updates. colab doesn't know how to update the version.

Answer (score 0):

I solved changing

```
%pip install -q accelerate transformers ftfy bitsandbytes==0.35.0 gradio natsort safetensors xformers
```

to

```
%pip install -q typing-extensions==4.5.0 kaleido accelerate transformers ftfy bitsandbytes==0.35.0 gradio natsort safetensors xformers
```

I was using a Colab notebook